# What are the rules around instantiation of template types (class/function) when taking an address?

Tags: c++, templates

In answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734492/c-callback-to-function-template-explicitly-instantiate-template) question, I came across this difference in behaviour with respect to template instantiation.

Initially there is a function template

```
template <typename T> void my_callback(void* data) { … }
```

Now something requires the address of this - specifically a `void*`, so the obvious approach is

```
bar(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&my_callback<int>));
```

However, with compiler versions pre gcc 4.5, this fails with a not-enough context... error. Fine - so the fix is to "cast" first - which forces instantiation, i.e:

```
void (*callback)(void*) = my_callback<int>;
bar(reinterpret_cast<void*>(callback));
```

This works fine.

Now the second scenario, rather than being a free function, it's a static member of a class template, i.e.

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  static void my_callback(void* data) {
    T& x = *static_cast<T*>(data);
    std:: cout << "Call[T] with " << x << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Now, the original `reinterpret_cast` works fine.

```
bar(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&foo<int>::my_callback));
```

So my question is - why this apparent difference in behaviour?

Comment: lol... borrowing from a quite recent question I see :) +1, the question is actually interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From n3290, 14.7.1 Implicit instantiation [temp.inst]

> 2 Unless a function template specialization has been explicitly
>   instantiated or explicitly specialized, the function template
>   specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is
>   referenced in a context that requires a function definition to exist.

There are similar rules in paragraph 1 for class template specializations. Notice that the Standard speaks in terms of specialization because a specialization is implicitly declared when a template is used an no user-provided specialization is here, at least for function templates (paragraph 8).

Combined with paragraph 10,

> 10 An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function
>   template, a member template, a non-virtual member function, a member
>   class, or a static data member of a class template that does not
>   require instantiation.

I think the rule of thumb is: as soon as an object/class member/function is needed or to make the program otherwise work (speaking informally), the template is implicitly instantiated but *no sooner*. This include taking the address of a function.

As to the question you linked, some uses of `reinterpret_cast` may make the program non-conformant, by which time it's irrelevant to mention instantiations -- [I invite you to see my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734492/c-callback-to-function-template-explicitly-instantiate-template/6735302#6735302)</shameless>.

Comment: so basically, to take the address of a member (even static), the type has to be instantiated - so the compiler will, but not for a free function because it doesn't need to... thx.

Comment: @Nim: Obtaining the address of a function requires the function definition (from which the linker will obtain the address), so obtaining the address of a template function should imply the instantiation of that particular specialization of the function.

Comment: @David, yes, which is why I asked, how come the reinterpret_cast of the address of doesn't work for a function template, tbh, I've not tried the indirect version as in Luc's answer yet.

Comment: @Nim It doesn't work because it doesn't have to. In the words of the n3290 draft for C++0x, casting from a function pointer type to an object pointer type is 'conditionally-supported'. C++03 offers even less guarantees I believe.