# How to parse a function and its arguments

Tags: c++, parsing, boost

For my lexer I'm using the `boost::wave` lexical iterator which gives me all the tokens from a `.cpp`, `.h` `.hpp` etc. file.

Now I want to find if a set of tokens i.e. an identifier followed by `open parenthesis` and then set of arguments separated by `comma` and finally `closed parenthesis`, is a function in a C++ program. I mean how should I analyze the set of tokens to make sure I have a function?

I am trying to implement this using a recursive descent parser. Till now my recursive descent parser can parse arithmetic expressions and take care of almost all kinds of operator precedence.

Or is there a function (in `boost::wave`) which can directly parse a function for me?

Also it would be helpful if somebody can suggest how I can find the `type` variable in the function argument. e.g. if I have a function:

```
int myfun(char* c, T& t1) { //... }
```

then how can I get tokens of `char` and `*` which can be treated as type of `c`.
Similarly tokens of  `T` and `&` which can be treated as type of `t1`?

EDIT: Here is a little more explanation to my question

references:

the boost wave documentation

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/wave/index.html

list of token identifiers

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/wave/doc/token_ids.html

```
typedef boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_token<> token_type;
typedef boost::wave::cpplexer::lex_iterator<token_type> token_iterator;
typedef token_type::position_type position_type;

position_type pos(filename);

//instr is the input file stream
token_iterator  it = token_iterator(instr.begin(), instr.end(), pos,
      boost::wave::language_support(
        boost::wave::support_cpp|boost::wave::support_option_long_long));
token_iterator  end = token_iterator();

//while it != end 
//...
boost::wave::token_id id = boost::wave::token_id(*it);

switch(id){
//...

    case boost::wave::T_IDENTIFIER:
      Match(id);//consumes one token and increments the token_iterator
        //get the token id of the next token       
      id = boost::wave::token_id(*it);
 //if an identifier is immediately followed by T_LEFTPAREN then it will be a function
      if(id == boost::wave::T_LEFTPAREN) {
        Match(id);                         (1)
        //this function i want to implement
        ParseFunction();                   (2) 
        Match(boost::wave::T_RIGHTPAREN);
      }
//...
}
```

So the question is how to implement the function ParseFunction()

Comment: You do realize that C++ is one of the hardest languages to parse correctly.

Comment: My take is that the OP is not parsing C++. I suspect the OP has a limited grammar to parse (homework?), something akin to `bc`.

Comment: @Martin: I am not interested in parsing a lot of C++, just a few things to get me going.

Comment: @David Hammen : not a homework.

Comment: What, exactly are you trying to do? The question is a bit unclear as-is. Are you trying to build a parse tree? Build an expression evaluator? Build a scriptable interface to your program? Something else? Edit your question so we can help you. Otherwise we're just going to squabble about whether POSIX and C/C++ are in conflict with one another (which doesn't help you a bit).

Comment: @Martin: Though some parts of the C++ grammar are not too hard.

Comment: @phresnel: You show me the simple part and I will show you the language that made it simpler.

Comment: @Martin: not too hard != simple. Will you be suggesting D or [SPECS](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/ModestProposal.html)?

Comment: @Martin: Of course it also depends on your target. For example, if you want just some intellisense-like function signature lookup, you can a long way with heuristical approaches that cover most cases. QtCreator does so, for example.

Answer (score -1):

If your system is POSIX-compliant (Linux, MacOSX, Solaris, ...) you can use `dlopen`/`dlsym` to determine whether the symbol exists. You need to watch out for name mangling, and on some systems you need to beware that [for example] the real name of `sin` is `_sin`.

Whether `dlsym` returns a pointer to a function or a pointer to some global variable — dlsym is clueless. In fact, you will have to do something that is very much contrary to both the C and C++ standards to use `dlsym`: you will have to cast the `void*` pointer returned by `dlsym` to a function pointer. The POSIX standard is in conflict with C/C++. That said, if you are on a POSIX-compliant system, those `void*` pointers will convert to a function pointer (otherwise the system is not POSIX-compliant).

---

**Edit:**

A huge gotcha: How do you call the thing you just found? How to you know how to handle the returned value, if there is any?

A simple example: suppose your input file contains `xsq = pow (x, 2)`. You have to know ahead of time that the signature of `pow` is `double pow (double, double)`.

Rather than using `dlsym` you are much better off handling a limited set of functions that you expressly build into your parser.

Comment: The recommended way by POSIX to cast function pointer types falls within implementation defined behavior, [or so I believe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734492/c-callback-to-function-template-explicitly-instantiate-template/6735302#6735302).

Comment: @Luc: You believe incorrectly. POSIX assumes (requires!) that function pointers be the same size as data pointers. There are many machines that do not support this. Harvard architecture machines, for instance. Casting a data pointer to a function pointer is undefined behavior, pure and simple. See http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2004/12/problem-with-dlsym/ .

Comment: But the recommended way to 'cast' function pointer types is to precisely sidestep the issue and cast from pointer to pointer to function to `void*`. Have you read my link?

Comment: @Luc: In fact, it is worse than UB. In C++ it is out-and-out illegal. C++ 2003: 5.4/5: "Any type conversion not mentioned below and not explicitly defined by the user (12.3) is ill-formed." There is no conversion from data pointer to function pointer, or vice versa. It is strictly forbidden by the C++ standard.

Comment: @Luc: Yes, I read your link. Did you read mine? (Second comment). THe POSIX standard is in conflict with both the C and C++ standards. You cannot legally cast a function pointer to/from void* in C or C++. Compilers on POSIX-compliant systems are faced with a lose-lose situation: If they truly are compliant with the C/C++ standards they cannot be POSIX-compliant, and if they are POSIX compliant they are in violation of the C/C++ standards.

Comment: I'm parsing a text (.cpp) file. Why would I need dlopen() etc. I tried to go through the description of dlopen(), still I'm not sure that I need dlopen().

Comment: @David What makes you think I did not already understand and know all this (and yes I did read the link)? What do you make of the [example code](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) from the specifications themselves? Can you see the difference between `void(*)()` and `void(**)()`?

Comment: @David: In that quote, "type conversion mentioned below" includes `reinterpret_cast`.  The specification for `reinterpret_cast` says: "Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported.  The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined..."

Comment: @Ben: You are reading a different standard than I am. I'm reading the 2003 standard, you are reading the draft C++0x standard.

Comment: @David: even in C++03, it's legal to `reinterpret_cast` from `void*` to `intptr_t` and from `intptr_t` to a function pointer.  The result is implementation-defined, but such a program is not ill-formed.  Therefore I don't believe that a compiler has to choose between POSIX compliance and C++ compliance.

Comment: @David: In addition, your whole answer seems completely irrelevant to the question.  Nothing in the question suggests that the expression is evaluated, or in fact that the function is called with any parameters whatsoever.  Finding function calls in C++ source code is useful for generating call trees, performing dead code identification, source browsing (think `ctags`), and so on.

Comment: Did you read the article to which I linked in comment number 2? Here's another, straight from WG21: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#195 . "In C the cast results in undefined behavior and thus does not require a diagnostic, and Unix C compilers generally do not issue one. This fact is used in the definition of the standard Unix function dlsym, which is declared to return void* but in fact may return either a pointer to a function or a pointer to an object. The fact that C++ compilers are required to issue a diagnostic is viewed as a "competitive disadvantage"."